# SetInterval() and async function? CPU working too hard with TF.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I have written a code for webcam classification in Tensorflow.js. By combining advice from many tutorials, it now works. However, in its current stage, it's very expensive for the system as the Tensorflow.js. predictions loop with `while (true)`. Google Chrome Helper (renderer) uses 50-60% of the CPU with this code running in the browser.

For me, it would be enough to make the prediction calculations every 0.5-1 seconds if that takes off some of the CPU strain. However, as a beginner I'm still confused how to add setInterval() to my current code (replacing the `while(true`) loop). I wonder if anyone could point me to right direction? Or if there is any other way to avoid the CPU strain with this code. Many thanks!

```
async function app() {

  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  console.log('Successfully loaded model');

  const labels = ["not_monster", "monster"];

  console.log(labels);


  const webcam = await tf.data.webcam(video);


  while (true) {


    tf.engine().startScope();
    const img = await webcam.capture();
    const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, [224, 224]);
    const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'float32');

    const t4d = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(resized.dataSync()),[1,224,224,3]);


    const result = await model.predict(t4d); 

    result.print(); 
    result.as1D().argMax().print(); 
    const labelIndex = result.as1D().argMax(); 
    const predictionLabel = result.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];

    
    const predict = await result.data();
    const value = predict[predictionLabel];



    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
       Numeric prediction is: ${labelIndex}\n
       The predicted label is: ${labels[predictionLabel]}\n
       Confidence is: ${value}\n
    `;

    if (labels[predictionLabel] == "monster"){ 
     var data = {
       speed: 100
     }
     socket.emit("monster", data);
    }

    else {
     socket.emit("not_monster"); 
    }

    img.dispose();
    result.dispose();
    smalImg.dispose();
    resized.dispose();
    t4d.dispose();
    tf.engine().endScope();
    await tf.nextFrame();

    
  } // closes loop

} // closes app

requestAnimationFrame(() => this.app());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a setinterval loop:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.app());
```

This works exactly like the same as:

```
setInterval(() => this.app(), 16.66666666667);
```

(well, almost exactly. It's hard to get exact millisecond value for 1/60 seconds).

So basically your app already have a giant while loop outside in the form of `requestAnimationFrame()` which you can also replace with `setInterval()` like I did above if you want to.

This causes `this.app()` to be called 60 times each second.

So, after one second of execution you will end up with 60 while loops running in the background (thanks to `await`).

After 10 seconds of execution you will end up with 600 while loops running in the background (waiting for 600 calls to Tensorflow).

After one minute you will be waiting for 3600 parallel calls to Tensorflow.

After 10 minutes that will end up awaiting for 36000 parallel calls to Tensorflow.

No wonder it is taking 60% CPU time. And it will get worse over time.

Before trying to replace `requestAnimationFrame()` with `setInterval()` I suggest you **delete the `while()` first**. You don't have to remove code inside the while loop just remove the `while (true) {` and `}` at the end.

The `requestAnimationFrame()` will try to call your function 60 times per second (basically acting as a while loop). If you want to run your function every 0.5 seconds instead replace it with:

```
setInterval(() => this.app(), 500);
```

To run your function every 1 second you do:

```
setInterval(() => this.app(), 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @slebetman, really useful answer that makes it all really clear. However, now with `setInterval(() => this.app(), 500);` I realize that the function is loading the model again (and cam stream) with each 0,5 seconds which drains the system even more. So I would need to call the stuff inside the former while loop with setInterval() and let the code before that run only once. I have tried this before with a separate function but ended up having trouble because the const model etc. were not recognized within my "loop function". Any advice on how to nest these?

Comment: Update: I was able to separate the prediction process with an asyncronous nested loop and setInterval() so the code works as wanted now!

Comment: +1 Always use requestAnimationFrame - it allows the browser to call your function when *it* is ready in case it is busy doing something, which reduces jankyness. Using a while (true) loop is bad as it is an infinite loop essentially that does not give resource to any other thing that may be happening. Even set interval is bad as you can not be sure an older device will be sure be able to execute within your time specified. RequestAnimationFrame will dynamically call when its safe to do so. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since requestAnimationFrame will run 'app' repeatedly no need to also loop in 'app'

```
  while (true) { ... }
```